# How to format data from string variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I have a NSString that keeps date:

```
1900-01-01T11:00:00
```

I need to format it, so I have a formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

How to format this string now?

```
NSString* formatedDateString = [df ???];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a date formatter, that returns a date object for for the given string, create a second date formatter, that returns a string in the desired format from that date.

```
NSDateformatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateformatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];  
[inputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateformatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateformatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];  

NSString *outputString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

---

But you could also let the output date formatter decide the style in respect to the locale:

```
NSDateformatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateformatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];  
[outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 
NSString *outputString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

for a american locale, you should now cat the desired format.

---

if you want to enforce format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" for the user, you should also set the locale of the output date formatter.

a complete command line example.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        NSString *dateString1 = @"2012-12-31T11:00:00";
        NSString *dateString2 = @"2012-12-31T14:00:00";
        NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [inputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

        NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [outputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];


        NSDate *date1 = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];
        NSDate *date2 = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString2];

        NSString *outputString1 = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
        NSString *outputString2 = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date2];

        NSLog(@"%@", outputString1);
        NSLog(@"%@", outputString2);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you dont set the locale like `[outputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];` it will lead do a ugly mix of formats with user's sefault locale, if it not happend to be 'en_US'

ie in German: `31/12/2012 02:00:00 nachm.` This is a format not used in german.

To support user's language and locale you should instead use the different styles.

---

The [q&a](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) rmaddy provided indicates, that there are rare cases, where the parse format gets rewritten. To avoid this, set the input formatted's format to a certain locale, like `[inputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`

Comment: Date that I have in initial string is '1900-01-01T11:00:00' with your code 'date' is null so the 'outputString' is also null

Comment: This is nightmare, I still getting null

Comment: @vikingosegundo You should set the locale of the first date formatter to en_US_POSIX to avoid issues with certain user locales or certain settings for 24-hour time. The 2nd formatter should be left as-is.

Comment: @rmaddy, the given dateString seems to be a iso 8601 timestamp, it is always 24h style, no matter of the user locale.

Comment: @vikingosegundo That's my point. The "string" is in a fixed format. This means that the date format needs to be in a fixed format. This requires the use of the en_US_POSIX locale. Please see [QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: with first formatter, do u mean mean the inputFormatter, or the first outputFormatter?

Comment: @vikingosegundo The input formatter. Your updated post is all wrong. You misquoted what I said. Please revise.

Comment: I dindt realize, you posted a link. Did u add it later?

Comment: @vikingosegundo No, the link was always in my post. You still need to redo your entire answer. Both sets of code you have posted are now wrong. It's the input formatter, not the output formatter, that needs the special locale.

Comment: The output formatter also should be given a locale, as otherwise some of the output will be formatted in the users locale. Ie English date format and German "vorm." instead of "am". And I already added that a locale should be set for parsing.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Using en_US_POSIX on the output format is not appropriate since it is for user display.

Comment: didnt I mention that? The OP asked for a specific format. You dont know, if it is for displaying. But as u see in my answer, I told him, to let the formatter decide by the users locale. (hint: it is the second block)

Comment: for displaying you shouldn't use any custom format. either styles or templates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two date formatter, one for parsing, one for formatting; Your parsing format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss" and your output format is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a". So, something like this :

```
NSString * targetString = @"1900-01-01'T'11:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *parseFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[parseFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"];
NSDate * date = [parseFormat dateFromString:targetString];

NSDateFormatter * outputFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
NSString * outputString = [parseFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: The format you have for parseFormat is incorrect. The T should be quoted. `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Thank you for correction! That is what I love in StackOverflow. You try to help people, and you end up getting helped ;)