# NSDate Output incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting date from [NSDate date] off by a few hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy H:mm"];

NSDate *start= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10-24-2012 12:15"];
NSDate *end  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10-24-2012 15:30"];
```

When I print out

```
   NSLog(@"------main_event start %@", start);
   NSLog(@"-----main_event end %@", end);
```

The result is

```
         ---main_event start 2012-10-24 19:15:00 +0000
         ---main_event end 2012-10-24 22:30:00 +0000
```

Now, it looks like the time added 7 hours automatically,  12:15 becomes 19:15, and 15:30 becomes 22:30.

Why?

Comment: Standard Objective-C question #6.

Answer (score 1):

because the timezone, where your device is located, is UTC-7.

The output is in UTC (hence the `+0000`), as a single NSDate will always print out it's time in UTC.

If you use an NSDateFormatter to output the date, it will take your locale in account. See my answer here: [NSDate date method returns wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454387/nsdate-date-method-returns-wrong-result/11454771#11454771)

Answer (score 0):

These are correct results. When you use `NSLog` to output an `NSDate` object, it displays in **GMT**. The parsing was done in your local timezone. `NSDate` objects are alway in **GMT**. If you want to print the NSDate object in your local timezone then you need an `NSDateFormatter` to print the date.

Comment: Note, that this is not totally correct: It is UTC, as GMT can differ from UTC due to the daylight saving time. GMT == (UTC+0|UTC+1)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time

Comment: @vikingosegundo Actually the docs state the time is output offset from GMT.

Comment: If you change the clock of you computer, and the location of the simulator to London, you will see, that for some dates you get +0100, na din winter +0000. I tried it out years ago. also: «UTC is synonymous with GMT, but GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community.» http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC

Comment: I understand there is a difference between **UTC** and **GMT**. I'm saying the docs for `NSDate` state that the timezone used in the `description` method is **GMT**.

Comment: the docs are wrong. but the terms are easy to mix up.

Comment: May I suggest you submit a documentation bug report to Apple. There is a link at the bottom of each page in the docs (at least in Xcode, not sure about online).

Comment: OK. That's an odd response from someone that is taking the time to offer their knowledge here to help others. Your choice of course. :)

Comment: the funny thing about the class reference of NSDate: they only chose example dates in winter, when there is no difference between GMT and UTC.

Comment: Let me say: I just wanted to be as pedantic, as you had been on my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975559/how-to-format-data-from-string-variable/12975760#12975760